# How to sort list of tuples by several keys

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am doing an exercise on Python and lists with one problem:
I have a list of tuples sorted by second key:

```
[('f', 3), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

And I need sort it: Second value by number and first value by alphabetical order. And it must look like:

```
[('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

When I used the `sorted` function I got:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]
```

It sorted by first element (and I lost arrangement of second). I also tried to use `key`:

```
def getKey(item):
  return item[0]
a = (sorted(lis, key=getKey))
```

And it didn't help me either.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getKey(item):
    return item[0]
```

This returns the first element of the tuple, so the list will be sorted by the first tuple element. You want to sort by second element, then first, so you want to reverse your tuple. Your key function would then need to be:

```
def getKey(item):
    return -item[1], item[0]
```

Making your final call:

```
>>> sorted(lis, key=getKey)
[('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have list sorted by second element of the tuple and I need sort by the first. Desirable result is: a 3, d 3, f 3, b 2, c2. In your solution the result is: [('f', 3), ('d', 3), ('a', 3), ('c', 2), ('b', 2)] Not what I need((

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [('f', 4), ('b', 4), ('a', 4), ('c', 3), ('k', 1)]
l.sort(key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))
print(l)
[('a', 4), ('b', 4), ('f', 4), ('c', 3), ('k', 1)]
```

We pass two keys to sort `-x[1]` which reverses the sort by numbers with the negative sign from highest to lowest, we then break ties with `x[0]` which is sorted from lowest to highest i.e a-z naturally.

`

Comment: Than'ks, but it not work in my program(( -as I've told already I have  a list sorted by second value and I need sort it by first to. When I use this code,  then:  list: [('f', 4), ('c', 3), ('b', 4), ('a', 4), ('k', 1)] come to  [('f', 4), ('b', 4), ('a', 4), ('c', 3), ('k', 1)] but must: [('a', 4), ('b', 4), ('f', 4), ('c', 3), ('k', 1)] ((

Comment: @PadraicCunningham would you mind explaining the `lambda` function please?

Comment: @Loupi. added some clarification, let me know if you don't understand anything

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Thank you for help it work! I spent almost two days to find the correct solution)  Now I'll be learn about lambda function)

Comment: @Mark_Louren, you're welcome. It is a bit tricky when you want to sort from low to high and high to low, if you wanted to reverse the letter sort you could use `-ord(x[0])` to negate.

Comment: I am still very confused as to how he wanted to sort it. In his question he said: "And I need sort it: Second value by number and first value by alphabetical order.". The output he wanted was just sorted by number and not by alphabet. Even in your answer `'c'` comes after `'f'` which is not alphabetical.

Comment: @louoi. The ties are sorted in alphabetical order

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm sorry I don't know what ties are. Can you please explain that as well?

Comment: @Loupi,take `('b', 4), ('a', 4)`  if we sort by number we will get the same output because `4 == 4` so then we look at the second element to break the tie so now the order becomes `('a', 4), ('b', 4)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham so in a sense the number get's preference?

Comment: @Loupi,  yes the the primary sort key is each number element [1] in each tuple, the ties are broken with element[0] the letter.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a list with nested tuples you cannot `sort` it by looking at both elements. In your case you can either `sort` by alphabetical order or numerical order. The `key` parameter of the `sort` method let's you specify by which element in the tuple pair you want to sort your data.

If you want to sort by increasing numerical order:

```
alist = [('f', 3), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
alist.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
```

If you want to sort by decreasing numerical order:

```
alist = [('f', 3), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
alist.sort(key = lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
```

If you want to sort by alphabetical order:

```
alist = [('f', 3), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
alist.sort()
```

Reverse alphabetical order:

```
alist = [('f', 3), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
alist.sort(reverse = True)
```

The `key` parameter let's you specify by which element of the tuple pair you want to sort by.
You cannot sort by both alphabetical and numerical order.

Comment: you don't need a lambda to sort by alphabetical order, just calling sort will do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I've got it. But what to do if I need sort by number and alphabetical at the same time? ideal output:  a 3, d 3, f 3, b 2, c 2 Maybe you can provide some useful links where I can find an anser?

Answer (score 0):

**Correct answer:**

```
l = [('f', 4), ('b', 4), ('a', 4), ('c', 3), ('k', 1)]
l.sort(key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))
print(l)
```

**Result:**
[('a', 4), ('b', 4), ('f', 4), ('c', 3), ('k', 1)]

Answer (score 0):

The `sort()` method is stable. Call it twice, first for the secondary key (alphabetically), then for the primary key (the number):

```
>>> lst = [('f', 3), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
>>> lst
[('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```